# material UI datagrid vertical scroll bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to render a material UI datagrid without any vertical scroll bar. this is the code for the grid:

```
return <div style={{height: 400, width: '100%', } }>
        <DataGrid className={classes.root} rows={closedPositions} columns={columns} rowHeight={20} 
headerHeight={25} disableSelectionOnClick pageSize={20} autoPageSize={true} scrollbarSize={1}
                  components={{
                      pagination: CustomPagination,
                  }}
        />
```

The documentation for autopageSize is:
`If true, the pageSize is calculated according to the container size and the max number of rows to avoid rendering a vertical scroll bar.`

I am very confused therefore as to why I have a scroll bar. even if i set the div to height 10,000 with no rows in the table, Ill still get a scroll bar.

Furthermore, there is no difference between scrollbarSize of 15 and 1 (for the horizontal scroll bar, which I want).

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Do you try below code?

```
autoHeight={true}
```

It's works fine to me.

Example.

```
<div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    autoHeight={true}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering! It's unclear where would you expect the OP to insert the code you wrote in your answer, could you please edit your answer so it could be easier to see how to use the property you suggested? I think adding the entire component tag would suffice.

Comment: Thank you your advice! I added the entire component tag.

Comment: it appeared to take away the scroll bar, but my grid is not honoring the 400 px height. its now much less

Comment: https://web-tools2-6mmkzmlse.vercel.app/sample1 It's your code. This page has a scrollbar, but this is for the browser, not for the DataGrid.